# Using VBA to create a named cell with defined variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to name a cell that will be referenced in a formulas using name manager via VBA. I have VBA locate the correct cell on the sheet (the location of which will vary) and define it as a variable:

```
s3form = Range(prog_beg3).Offset(0, 3)
```

I then name the cell using the name manager functionality so that the cell has the address of 's3form' but with the row being variable. So if 's3form = B5', the address of the named cell would be '$B5'.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=s3_form, RefersTo:=s3form
```

However, the formula then doesn't recognize s3form as a cell. It seems to only recognize the cell when 's3form = $B$5'

Does anyone have a possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: Use `Set`: `Set s3form = Range(prog_beg3).Offset(0, 3)`  Of course `s3form` must be declared as a range.  Then `RefersTo:=s3form.Address`

Comment: @ScottCraner When I try 
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=sform, RefersTo:=s3form.Address 
I get Run-time error '424' Object required

Comment: Please show more of your code.  How are your variables declared and assigned values?

Comment: `Range(prog_end2).Offset(4, 0).Select
    prog_beg3 = Selection.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)`

`s3form = Sheets("testmode").Range(prog_beg3).Offset(0, 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=True)`

`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=sform, RefersTo:=s3form.Address`

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

```
activeworkbook.Names.Add "Testing",[s3form]
```

Now "Testing" would be added to the names in the workbook, refering to s3form. Concerning your code, it should probably work if you use the `[]` around `s3form`.

In general, these `[]` are a nice way to refer to named ranges. You may refer even to addresses like this - `[A1]`.

Comment: I tried this but the formulas still doesn't recognize the cell. In name manager, it says that the name refers to $I31, which is correct, but says that the value is also $I31. Perhaps the value needs to be blank in order for the formula to recognize it?

Comment: @A.Nelson - I am missing some bits of information, but try the following -> After declaring the `s3form` as a named range, in order to fill it with some value, refer it like this: `[s3form] = Range(prog_beg3).Offset(0, 3)`